# how to change new products block heading in magento 1.9

Tags: widget, magento-1.9, static-block

I have added a new products static block with widget on my home page. I am not able to change heading of this block. Is there any way to change it.

Comment: Do you want to change title of the block?

Comment: yes, The default title is shown "New Products"

Comment: How you can get products in static block?

Comment: You can find title in the following files.
catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml and
catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find title in the following files.

```
> catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml 
> catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml
```